# Java Swing JTextField.getText is not returning anything

Tags: java, swing

For some reason **getText** is not working for a text field.

Perhaps I am doing something wrong with this.

```
    private JTextField txtTemp;
    txtTemp = new JTextField();
    txtTemp.setBounds(350, 57, 86, 20);
    mainPanel.add(txtTemp);
    txtTemp.setColumns(10);

    String filePath = txtTemp.getText();
    System.out.println("File path is" +filePath);
```

Nothing is being printed when something is typed in the text box.

I also did it with using an action listener.  Load the program, and have the user add some text.

```
    btnTest = new JButton("TEST");
    btnTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String filePath = txtTemp.getText();
            System.out.println("File path is" +filePath);
        }
    });
```

Still returns blank.

Any ideas?

Comment: From your provided code, no text was ever put into the text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out this issue.

At the top if i declare and Instantiate the object it works.

```
private JTextField txtTemp = new JTextField();
```

Answer (score 2):

> "Nothing is being printed when something is typed in the text box."... "Still returns blank."

Sounds like you want something to happen whenever the text field is being type into. For that we would use a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html), which listener for changes in the underlying [`Document`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) of the text field.

```
final JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { printText(); }
    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { printText(); }
    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { printText(); }

    private void printText() {
        System.out.println(field.getText());
    }
});
```

- See more explanation at [How to Write a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

---

Aside, if you want something to happen when the use type <kbd>enter</kbd>, then add an `ActionListener` to the text field.

Answer (score 1):

Your JTextField seems empty, as long as you dont give any input, however common mistakes may be:

is it editable?

```
 txtTemp.setEditable(true);
```

any text added?

```
 public void changeTxtField(String text)
{
    txtTemp.setText(text);
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

your code looks fine so

Answer (score 0):

Don't also do it **'also in the Action Listener'**  , DO it **only** in the ActionListener ?

I have no idea where you are going wrong , are you expecting the output on the GUI screen ?if so you are mistaken , look into the terminal...

Here I just tried and it perfectly works , it prints  the user input text after clicking the button onto the terminal ,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class TestText{
public static void main(String[] args)

{

JFrame frame=new JFrame("TextFieldTest");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JPanel mainPanel=new JPanel();


     JTextField txtTemp;
    txtTemp = new JTextField();
    txtTemp.setBounds(350, 57, 86, 20);
    mainPanel.add(txtTemp);
    txtTemp.setColumns(10);


JButton  btnTest = new JButton("TEST");

    btnTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String filePath = txtTemp.getText();
            System.out.println("File path is" +filePath);
        }
    });

frame.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,btnTest);
frame.add(mainPanel);
frame.setSize(600,600);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);

}//main ends


}//class ends
```